# Host legacy WCF services in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone know what the options are for hosting legacy .NET4+ WCF services in Azure?
I have heard that App Services are not to be used, but I have trouble finding any sources.

Comment: I have a few in production on app services, and they work just fine.

Comment: @DerekGusoff is that the same kind of app service that I would use for deploying a newly created aspnet (rest/webapi) app?

Answer (score 2):

The basic areas to consider when migrating an existing .NET application to Azure are:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/migration/choose

- Compute choices
- Database choices
- Networking and security considerations
- Authentication and authorization considerations

To host a WCF service in Azure, you can check out the following tutorials.
[Expose an on-premises WCF service to a web application in the cloud by using Azure Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay) 
[Deploying an existing WCF service to Azure](https://www.advaiya.com/deploying-an-existing-wcf-service-to-azure/)

Answer (score 1):

You can host your WCF services in multiple ways

- on IIS
- as Windows Service
- as Console App

For the windows Service / Console App, you can:

- Setup a VM and also install it

For the other options:

You can deploy on App Service or also on a VM with IIS installed.

More info:

https://aspdotnetcodehelp.wordpress.com/2017/11/13/hosting-wcf-in-azure-app-service/